# How do I add my IoT device as skill on the Google Home?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I have created an IoT device with WiFi connectivity.

How can I add this device as a new skill on my Google Home and   control it through voice command?

The image below shows the "Feit Electric" skill on the Google Home.  How can I add my own device in a similar way?

[image: Image of the Feit Electric skill showing setup process]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a Google Assistant Smart Home Action and publish it.

The API you need to follow is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/create).

This will require a cloud service and a way for the cloud service to connect to the device (While Google have recently added local control, there still needs to be a cloud service for discovery/account linking/fallback control).

Comment: is it ok for create cloud  serivice like adafruit?

Comment: please specify in detail

Comment: The link I have provided has all the details you need and includes links to sample projects, but how to do this is far too complex to include in a single answer here.

Comment: f rom where to get the privacy policy link?

Comment: You need to write one and host it somewhere. It is the privacy policy for the service you need to write.

Comment: is it need to create Auth0 ?

Comment: Read the Google docs, it explains everything you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96901/discussion-between-shavan-we-and-hardillb).